# Merging two pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two csv files,and if I do:

```
df_compiler = pd.read_csv('sub_compiler.csv')
```

I obtain:

[image]

and for the other csv file I do:

```
df_opt = pd.read_csv('sub_opt.csv')
```

I obtain:

[image]

now what I would like to do is merge these two csv files and obtain something like:

[image]

can somebody please help me doing this? Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally suggest something like

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_compiler, df_opt, on="instructions")
```

But the third image you posted does not really look like the inner merge of the other two. Can you describe what exactly you are trying to achieve in a little more detail? The third one looks like ten times longer than the other two.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually wrote wrongly the question, an I think the best thing to do I to write another question instead of change this.  Sorry .

Comment: The usual way is to edit your question through the grey *edit* button. Also, please avoid posting images of code or data when possible: the data subset would be better as correctly rendered text.